# Downloading AWS Lambda Zip using Boto3 fails

Tags: python, lambda, zip, boto3

I'm trying to setup up a workflow that allows me and my fellow developers remotely work on our AWS Lambda functions and I'm running into a issue with downloading the remote Zip of said functions and would appreciate some help.

Everything appears to work, but nothing gets extracted and printing the file list reveals a empty array.
As you can tell from my smathering of print statements that I've tried to ensure nothing is reporting a issue.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
 url = function_config['Code']['Location']
     print(function_config['Code']['RepositoryType'])
     check = None
     while not check:
         r = requests.get(url,stream =True)
         print(r.status_code)
         check = is_zipfile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
                            
     else:
         # extract and overwrite
         try:
             zipped_package = ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
             print(zipped_package.namelist())
             zipped_package.extractall(directory_path+ 'test/')
         except Exception as e:
             print('Exception Zipping file. Skipping')
             print('Exception: {}'.format(e))
             continue
```

Edit: If there is any other information I can provide, please ask.
Edit 2: This is not running in Lambda, but as part of the back end code for a web app.

Comment: In lambda you can write only to `/tmp/` directory. Make sure that your `directory_path` is located there.

Comment: @taras I probably should have clarified. This code isn't running in Lmbda. It's just trying to download a Lambda function. The /tmp/ restriction should not be a issue.